# How to insert null value when datatype error is fired using Bulk Insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm using Bulk Insert command in T-SQL cause I have a too big csv file. This file has fields that use numeric datatypes like float, but in these fields sometimes there are data with strings like "S/N".

So, how can I force that fields to NULL when I get an string value while I'm inserting?

Now I'm using this command, can you help me?

```
BULK INSERT [CUBOS_FINDIRECT].[dbo].[ListadoRobinsonTXT] 
    FROM '\\10.0.20.17\d$\listadoRobinson\listadoRobinsonDef.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    )
```

Thank you in advance so much.

Comment: You can't, what you can do is bulk load into a temporary holding table, and move it to the actual target from there.

Comment: An alternative to the staging table is an ETL process that reads the file, transforms non-conformant values to NULL, and bulk inserts the rows. That could be done in PowerShell using `SqlBulkCopy`.